# Is each element of a List<T> boxed?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, boxing

A boxed `T` can only be unboxed to `T`. For example, this is not working:

```
object o1 = 5;
double n3 = (double)o1;
```

Using the Linq's `Cast()` method on a `List<T>` throws a similar exception:

```
List<int> _numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
// this is also not working
IEnumerable<double> nums = _numbers.Cast<double>();
```

1. Does that mean that each element of a `List<T>` is boxed ?
2. Is it possible to cast each element of the `List<>` without creating a copy of the list ? 
   (Please do not post any answer with the Linq's `Select()` method, since it is creating a copy of the collection)

Comment: A string will never be boxed, as it already **is** an object. Boxing only applies to valuetypes. And yes, boxing requires to create a new (boxed) object, so no, you cannot "cast" your list of numbers to another number-type

Comment: But `_numbers.Select(n => (double)n))` works. Of course value types are not boxed when storing in a `List<valuetype>`.

Comment: There is no boxing going on in the `List<T>`. Generics have two separate runtime implementations; one for references, one for values. `Enumerable.Cast` is specifically intended to cast items from a non-generic `IEnumerable`, however, so when you do this you *do* get boxing as the items are first boxed, then attempted to be unboxed as `double` -- but this is specific to `Enumerable.Cast`. And no -- `.Select()` does *not* create a copy of the collection, it creates an iteration -- just as `.Cast` does, so if you don't like one you shouldn't like the other either.

Comment: For first example you can use [Convert.ToDouble()](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bvtu7B), similarly for second `_numbers.Select()` with converting should also do. `List<int>` won't become `List<double>` without something.

Comment: To add to @JeroenMostert's comment, `Cast` is an extension method on `IEnumerable`, and `IEnumerable.Current` is an `object`, which means that every `int` will be boxed as the `Cast` method retrieves it from the `IEnumerable`. If you want to create a list of doubles from your list of ints you will need to create new list. If you just want an `IEnumerable<double>`, then `Select` is the correct tool for the job, and does *not* copy the whole list

Comment: @JeroenMostert If I remember it is false... There is a single implementation for all the reference types plus a specialized implementation for each type of value type (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time))

Comment: @xanatos: yes, couldn't edit my comment in time unfortunately. I should have said there are two *kinds* of runtime implementations for generics, not *exactly* two.

Comment: _"A boxed T can only be unboxed to T"_ - technically this is not true. Try this: `int i = 42; object o = i; long l = (long)(DateTimeKind)o;`

Comment: @vasily.sib That can be simplified to `object o = 42; var d = (DateTimeKind)o;`, so you can unbox to an enum that uses the same basetype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will speak here only of value types. Reference types follow different rules.

1. Does that mean that each element of a `List<T>` is boxed ?

No. Java does it, erases all the types `T` at runtime and redirect all the types to a single `List<Object>` implementation (it is called [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)). In .NET, for value types, every `List<ValueType1>`, `List<ValueType2>`, `List<ValueType3>` receives a distinct implementation at runtime (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time)).

2. Is it possible to cast each element of the `List<>` without creating a copy of the list ?

When you cast a value type to something to else you are making a copy of it. Often on the stack, but the copy exists. You can't simply access a value type as a different value type.

[For example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMCAbNgCyYCyCAFBAPYB2A5puwJSHFSQ+nCZMw7YLz4BuQSQC+qeWWxVaDUROA9+RFEKUoFQA===):

```
public static void M1(long n) {
    M2((int)n);
}

public static void M2(int n) {
}
```

is translated in IL asm to

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: conv.i4
IL_0002: call void C::M2(int32)
IL_0007: ret
```

Where [`conv.i4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i4?view=net-5.0):

> If the conversion is successful, the resulting value is pushed onto the stack.

Note that even *getting out* an element of `List<int>` causes a copy to be made: you aren't accessing the element INSIDE the `List<int>`:

```
public void M1(List<int> a) {
    int v = a[0];
    v = 6; // this won't modify a[0]
}
```

With arrays (and with newer C#) you can access directly the element of an array:

```
public void M1(int[] a) {
    ref int r = ref a[0];
    r = 6; // this will modify a[0]
}
```

The difference here is that the indexer of `List<T>` (the things that is called when you make a `var foo = list[5]` is a *method*, while the indexer of an array is an IL instruction (array are defined at the lowest level in the .NET virtual machine, and the have special OPs to handle them, `List<T>` are built "on top" of arrays). Even this can be easily seen on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqqMAzNnJgMKYDeqmD2ZMumAsggBQAyYAzsAA8YAHbAAfJgCGASlr1Gi0cEwA3TAF5pAbXQBdQikWL1WgGz5MAeiuZgAC36YA7gHsRAchUBbVwBMwADMATx19BQYAXyIjRlJsVg5OZW09aTk6WONMACcAU0DMZVzNXIKwgwjjHNKLa1sHJ2dICExfAJCKqsjFVEigA).